# apache-tomcat-10.1.13 fail to startup ,after instatllation .I have already set CATALINA_HOME and JAVA_HOME in the system variables

Tags: windows, tomcat, installation, operating-system, startup

```
C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.1.13\bin>startup
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.1.13"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.1.13"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.1.13\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.1.13\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.1.13\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
```

I  am getting this in the commandline.

I have set the required  system variables and run startup in command line  expecting to see the server startup message but it stopped at the line
`Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""`
in the commandline.

Comment: Screenshot would be a good addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat 10.1.x requires a minimum of Java 11. You are using Java 8. You need to switch to Java 11 or later.

There will likely be an error message in the log files in `C:\Program Files\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.1.13\logs`.